# Get classroom available hours between date time range

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, plsql

I'm, using Oracle 11g and I have this problem. I couldn't come up with any ideas to solve it yet.

I have a table with occupied classrooms. What I need to find are the hours available between a datetime range. For example, I have rooms A, B and C, the table of occupied classrooms looks like this:

```
Classroom        start                 end  
   A         10/10/2013 10:00      10/10/2013 11:30  
   B         10/10/2013 09:15      10/10/2013 10:45  
   B         10/10/2013 14:30      10/10/2013 16:00
```

What I need to get is something like this:

`with date time range between '10/10/2013 07:00' and '10/10/2013 21:15'`

```
Classroom    avalailable_from        available_to  
   A         10/10/2013 07:00      10/10/2013 10:00  
   A         10/10/2013 11:30      10/10/2013 21:15  
   B         10/10/2013 07:00      10/10/2013 09:15  
   B         10/10/2013 10:45      10/10/2013 14:30  
   B         10/10/2013 16:00      10/10/2013 21:15  
   C         10/10/2013 07:00      10/10/2013 21:15
```

Is there a way I can accomplish that with sql or pl/sql?

Comment: What have you thought uptil now?

Comment: what i have until now is something like this:
select ui.* from occupied_class oc                                       
where (to_date('10/10/2013 07:00', 'dd/MM/RR hh24:mi') BETWEEN oc.start AND oc.end                                      
OR to_date('10/10/2013 21:15', 'dd/MM/RR hh24:mi') BETWEEN oc.start AND oc.end
OR oc.start BETWEEN to_date('10/10/2013 07:00', 'dd/MM/RR hh24:mi') AND to_date('10/10/2013 21:15', 'dd/MM/RR hh24:mi')
OR oc.end BETWEEN to_date('10/10/2013 07:00', 'dd/MM/RR hh24:mi') AND to_date('10/10/2013 21:15', 'dd/MM/RR hh24:mi')).
But that will only get me Classroom C

Comment: Will only get me classroom C as available

Comment: You can do it in PL\SQL. Good if you know your segments, lets say, 15 minute segments. Than you can create Array of 15 minute segments for each room. You will know how many segments you have because there are room hours. Let say 7Am to 6Pm - you have 44 segments. Then you fill these segments based on Start and End time. After that, read empty segments and create available time spans. For example, if segments 3,4 and 5 are emply, you can say that 7:30 Am to 8:15 Am room is available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was looking at a solution similar in concept at least to Wernfried's, but I think it's different enough to post as well. The start is the same idea, first generating the possible time slots, and assuming you're looking at 15-minute windows: I'm using CTEs because I think they're clearer than nested selects, particularly with this many levels.

```
with date_time_range as (
  select to_date('10/10/2013 07:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') as date_start,
    to_date('10/10/2013 21:15', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') as date_end
  from dual
),
time_slots as (
  select level as slot_num,
    dtr.date_start + (level - 1) * interval '15' minute as slot_start,
    dtr.date_start + level * interval '15' minute as slot_end
  from date_time_range dtr
  connect by level <= (dtr.date_end - dtr.date_start) * (24 * 4) -- 15-minutes
)
select * from time_slots;
```

This gives you the 57 15-minute slots between the start and end date you specified. The CTE for `date_time_range` isn't strictly necessary, you could put your dates straight into the `time_slots` conditions, but you'd have to repeat them and that then introduces a possible failure point (and means binding the same value multiple times, from JDBC or wherever).

Those slots can then be cross-joined to the list of classrooms, which I'm assuming are already in another table, which gives you 171 (3x57) combinations; and those can be compared with existing bookings - once those are eliminated you're left with the 153 15-minute slots that have no booking.

```
with date_time_range as (...),
time_slots as (...),
free_slots as (
  select c.classroom, ts.slot_num, ts.slot_start, ts.slot_end,
    lag(ts.slot_end) over (partition by c.classroom order by ts.slot_num)
      as lag_end,
    lead(ts.slot_start) over (partition by c.classroom order by ts.slot_num)
      as lead_start
  from time_slots ts
  cross join classrooms c
  left join occupied_classrooms oc on oc.classroom = c.classroom
    and not (oc.occupied_end <= ts.slot_start 
      or oc.occupied_start >= ts.slot_end)
  where oc.classroom is null
)
select * from free_slots;
```

But then you have to collapse those into contiguous ranges. There are various ways of doing that; here I'm peeking at the previous and next rows to decide if a particular value is the edge of a range:

```
with date_time_range as (...),
time_slots as (...),
free_slots as (...),
free_slots_extended as (
  select fs.classroom, fs.slot_num,
    case when fs.lag_end is null or fs.lag_end != fs.slot_start
      then fs.slot_start end as slot_start,
    case when fs.lead_start is null or fs.lead_start != fs.slot_end
      then fs.slot_end end as slot_end
  from free_slots fs
)
select * from free_slots_extended
where (fse.slot_start is not null or fse.slot_end is not null);
```

Now we're down to 12 rows. (The outer `where` clause eliminates all 141 of the 153 slots from the previous step which are mid-range, since we only care about the edges):

```
CLASSROOM   SLOT_NUM SLOT_START       SLOT_END       
--------- ---------- ---------------- ----------------
A                  1 2013-10-10 07:00                  
A                 12                  2013-10-10 10:00 
A                 19 2013-10-10 11:30                  
A                 57                  2013-10-10 21:15 
B                  1 2013-10-10 07:00                  
B                  9                  2013-10-10 09:15 
B                 16 2013-10-10 10:45                  
B                 30                  2013-10-10 14:30 
B                 37 2013-10-10 16:00                  
B                 57                  2013-10-10 21:15 
C                  1 2013-10-10 07:00                  
C                 57                  2013-10-10 21:15
```

So those represent the edges, but on separate rows, and a final step combines them:

```
...
select distinct fse.classroom,
  nvl(fse.slot_start, lag(fse.slot_start)
    over (partition by fse.classroom order by fse.slot_num)) as slot_start,
  nvl(fse.slot_end, lead(fse.slot_end)
    over (partition by fse.classroom order by fse.slot_num)) as slot_end
from free_slots_extended fse
where (fse.slot_start is not null or fse.slot_end is not null)
```

Or putting all that together:

```
with date_time_range as (
  select to_date('10/10/2013 07:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') as date_start,
    to_date('10/10/2013 21:15', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI') as date_end
  from dual
),
time_slots as (
  select level as slot_num,
    dtr.date_start + (level - 1) * interval '15' minute as slot_start,
    dtr.date_start + level * interval '15' minute as slot_end
  from date_time_range dtr
  connect by level <= (dtr.date_end - dtr.date_start) * (24 * 4) -- 15-minutes
),
free_slots as (
  select c.classroom, ts.slot_num, ts.slot_start, ts.slot_end,
    lag(ts.slot_end) over (partition by c.classroom order by ts.slot_num)
      as lag_end,
    lead(ts.slot_start) over (partition by c.classroom order by ts.slot_num)
      as lead_start
  from time_slots ts
  cross join classrooms c
  left join occupied_classrooms oc on oc.classroom = c.classroom
    and not (oc.occupied_end <= ts.slot_start
      or oc.occupied_start >= ts.slot_end)
  where oc.classroom is null
),
free_slots_extended as (
  select fs.classroom, fs.slot_num,
    case when fs.lag_end is null or fs.lag_end != fs.slot_start
      then fs.slot_start end as slot_start,
    case when fs.lead_start is null or fs.lead_start != fs.slot_end
      then fs.slot_end end as slot_end
  from free_slots fs
)
select distinct fse.classroom,
  nvl(fse.slot_start, lag(fse.slot_start)
    over (partition by fse.classroom order by fse.slot_num)) as slot_start,
  nvl(fse.slot_end, lead(fse.slot_end)
    over (partition by fse.classroom order by fse.slot_num)) as slot_end
from free_slots_extended fse
where (fse.slot_start is not null or fse.slot_end is not null)
order by 1, 2;
```

Which gives:

```
CLASSROOM SLOT_START       SLOT_END       
--------- ---------------- ----------------
A         2013-10-10 07:00 2013-10-10 10:00 
A         2013-10-10 11:30 2013-10-10 21:15 
B         2013-10-10 07:00 2013-10-10 09:15 
B         2013-10-10 10:45 2013-10-10 14:30 
B         2013-10-10 16:00 2013-10-10 21:15 
C         2013-10-10 07:00 2013-10-10 21:15
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6ea0c1/1).

Comment: I didn´t know half of this things. This is my first question in stackoverflow and i'm greeatful there's a lot of people willing to help here. I hope i can help others here soon, bu ti have to learn a lot

Comment: Don't we all! Having seen your recent comment, I [checked that this seems to work with two adjacent bookings](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/99d0c/1).

Answer (score 2):

It is always a challenge when you like to "select something which does not exist". First you need a list of all available classrooms and times (in interval of 15 Minutes). Then you can select them by skipping the occupied items.

I managed to make a query without any PL/SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (Classroom VARCHAR2(10), start_ts DATE, end_ts DATE);    
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('A', TIMESTAMP '2013-01-10 10:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2013-01-10 11:30:00');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('B', TIMESTAMP '2013-01-10 09:15:00', TIMESTAMP '2013-01-10 10:45:00');
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES ('B', TIMESTAMP '2013-01-10 14:30:00', TIMESTAMP '2013-01-10 16:00:00');



WITH all_rooms AS
    (SELECT CHR(64+LEVEL) AS ROOM FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3),
all_times AS
    (SELECT  CAST(TIMESTAMP '2013-01-10 07:00:00' + (LEVEL-1) * INTERVAL '15' MINUTE AS DATE) AS TIMES, LEVEL AS SLOT
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY TIMESTAMP '2013-01-10 07:00:00' + (LEVEL-1) * INTERVAL '15' MINUTE <= TIMESTAMP '2013-01-10 21:15:00'),
all_free_slots AS
    (SELECT ROOM, TIMES, SLOT, 
        CASE SLOT-LAG(SLOT, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY ROOM ORDER BY SLOT) 
            WHEN 1 THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END AS NEW_WINDOW 
    FROM all_times
        CROSS JOIN all_rooms
    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
        (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE ROOM = CLASSROOM AND TIMES BETWEEN START_TS + INTERVAL '1' MINUTE AND END_TS - INTERVAL '1' MINUTE)),
free_time_windows AS
    (SELECT ROOM, TIMES, SLOT, 
        SUM(NEW_WINDOW) OVER (PARTITION BY ROOM ORDER BY SLOT) AS WINDOW_ID
    FROM all_free_slots)
SELECT ROOM, 
    TO_CHAR(MIN(TIMES), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') AS free_time_start, 
    TO_CHAR(MAX(TIMES), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') AS free_time_end
FROM free_time_windows
GROUP BY ROOM, WINDOW_ID
HAVING MAX(TIMES) - MIN(TIMES) > 0
ORDER BY ROOM, 2;


ROOM FREE_TIME_START    FREE_TIME_END
---- ----------------------------------
A    2013-01-10 07:00   2013-01-10 10:00
A    2013-01-10 11:30   2013-01-10 21:15
B    2013-01-10 07:00   2013-01-10 09:15
B    2013-01-10 10:45   2013-01-10 14:30
B    2013-01-10 16:00   2013-01-10 21:15
C    2013-01-10 07:00   2013-01-10 21:15
```

In order to understand the query you can split the sub-queries from top, e.g.

```
WITH all_rooms AS
    (SELECT CHR(64+LEVEL) AS ROOM FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3),
all_times AS
    (SELECT  CAST(TIMESTAMP '2013-01-10 07:00:00' + (LEVEL-1) * INTERVAL '15' MINUTE AS DATE) AS TIMES, LEVEL AS SLOT
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY TIMESTAMP '2013-01-10 07:00:00' + (LEVEL-1) * INTERVAL '15' MINUTE <= TIMESTAMP '2013-01-10 21:15:00')
SELECT ROOM, TIMES, SLOT, 
    CASE SLOT-LAG(SLOT, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY ROOM ORDER BY SLOT) 
        WHEN 1 THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END AS NEW_WINDOW 
FROM all_times
    CROSS JOIN all_rooms
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TABLE1 WHERE ROOM = CLASSROOM AND TIMES BETWEEN START_TS + INTERVAL '1' MINUTE AND END_TS - INTERVAL '1' MINUTE)
ORDER BY ROOM, SLOT
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I missed that. Perhaps you have to play a bit with `CASE SLOT-LAG(SLOT, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY ROOM ORDER BY SLOT) 
            WHEN 1 THEN 0
            ELSE 1
        END AS NEW_WINDOW` or `TIMES BETWEEN START_TS AND END_TS` (maybe add or substract one Minute somewhere).

Comment: Yes; shame I can't upvote it again really *8-) Finding the windows is quite a bit simpler than my attempt. Nice.

Comment: @Wernfried It works, but it has a problem with adjacent hours as i show in the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/497b0/1/0)

Comment: Yes, I see. I added this line to the clause, then it works. `HAVING MAX(TIMES) - MIN(TIMES) > 0`