# MySQL/MariaDB: Summing multiple disparate worktime invertals to determine when an office is open?

Tags: mysql, sql, time, mariadb, schedule

I am working with a patient management system that has flexible scheduling options for providers. I would like to infer the number of hours that a clinic (aka office) is open, given that providers can start and stop their shifts at any time and that a provider can have multiple shifts in a single day. I am using MariaDB 10.3

This image shows the schedule of two providers, Dr. K and Dr. P.

[image: Picture of provider schedule]

- Dr. K and Dr. P start their day at 6:00 AM. They work for two hours and then stop for a two hour break at 8:00 AM. The clinic was open for 2hrs.
- Dr. K and Dr. P then start working again at 10:00 AM. They stop again at 12:00 PM for lunch. The clinic was open for 2hrs.
- Dr. P starts his shift at 2:00 PM and finishes up at 6:00 PM. Dr. K starts his shift later at 4:00 PM and finishes at 6:30 PM. The clinic was open for 4.5 hrs

The total hours that this clinic is scheduled as open is 8.5 (2 hr + 2 hr + 4.5)

There is no indication or flag in the database of a break or time closed of any sort. It must be inferred from the StartTime and StopTime columns.

My initial consideration was to use a recursive CTE to build a list of empty time slots and then subtract the sum of those time slots from the min starttime and max stoptime for the day similar to [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238990/get-classroom-available-hours-between-date-time-range).  But the clinic is only closed when *all* providers are not working, which kind of throws a wrench in the works.

Relevant table and fiddle:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pfNN1NJMAZB76EaPhinzsF/0

```
CREATE TABLE `scheduletest` (
    `ScheduleNum` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `SchedDate` DATE NULL,
    `StartTime` TIME NULL,
    `StopTime` TIME NULL,
    `ProvNum` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

CREATE TABLE `providertest` (
    `ProvNum` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `Abbr` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

INSERT INTO `providertest` (`ProvNum`,`Abbr`) VALUES 
(1,'DR K')
,(2,'DR P')
;

INSERT INTO `scheduletest` (`ScheduleNum`,`SchedDate`,`StartTime`,`StopTime`,`ProvNum`) VALUES 
(79786,'2019-06-06','06:00:00','08:00:00',1)
,(79787,'2019-06-06','10:00:00','12:00:00',1)
,(79788,'2019-06-06','06:00:00','08:00:00',2)
,(79789,'2019-06-06','10:00:00','12:00:00',2)
,(79790,'2019-06-06','14:00:00','18:00:00',2)
,(79791,'2019-06-06','16:00:00','18:30:00',1)
;
```

Comment: It would be quite messy in SQL.  Consider doing it in you application code, while having MySQL be the persistent repository for the data.